# Split data of a pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = [{"username": "last",
"time_data": "{\"hours\":[{\"hour\":\"00:00\",\"postCount\":\"5\",\"topicCount\":\"3\",\"totalCount\":80},{\"hour\":\"01:00\",\"postCount\":\"11\",\"topicCount\":\"6\",\"topciCount\":31}"
},
{"username": "truk",
 "time_data": "{\"hours\":[{\"hour\":\"00:00\",\"postCount\":\"11\",\"topicCount\":\"6\",\"totalCount\":362},{\"hour\":\"01:00\",\"postCount\":\"22\",\"topicCount\":\"8\",\"topicCount\":355}"
}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

I have used this code to get the "postCount" of both '00:00' and '01:00':

```
df_h0 = df.copy()
df_h0['hour']='00:00'
df_h0['totalCount']=df.time_data.str.split('"00:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h0 = df_h0.fillna(0)

df_h1 = df.copy()
df_h1['hour']='01:00'
df_h1['totalCount']=df.time_data.str.split('"01:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h1 = df_h1.fillna(0)

df_tot = df_h0.append([df_h1])
df_tot.head()
```

But now I want to get the "totalCount" which is not just next to the hours. Anyone knows how to do that?

Expected output:

```
                           time_data                 username   hour    totalCount
0   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"5","top...   last    00:00   80
1   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"11","to...   truk    00:00   362
0   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"5","top...   last    01:00   31
1   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"11","to...   truk    01:00   355
```

Comment: Which pandas version are you on? What is the output of `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: The output is: 0.24.2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to manually parse a JSON file, have you looked into using Python's [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library instead?

Pandas also has functionality to create dataframes from JSON files, [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

Both of these may make it easier for you to parse your data.